# Showing org headings in uppercase

Tags: org-mode, faces

I found coloured headings disturbing so I `(setq org-level-color-stars-only t)`.  But now the headings are too similar to regular text, and their face is `default` so they can't be formatted by changing a face.

Question: how can I display all headings in uppercase without actually upcasing them?

It would be nice to have a function for toggling uppercase(dly displayed) headings.

Comment: Something like that can easily be done with display text property or overlays. The real difficulty is that Orgmode does similar things that will interfer.

Comment: @Tobias can you be more specific. I tried with overlays and it works fine so far.

Comment: BTW here's what I tried: `(org-map-entries (lambda () (when (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp) (overlay-put (make-overlay (match-beginning 4) (match-end 4)) 'display (upcase (match-string 4))))))`

Comment: @jagrg Examples are: `org-columns` which is not playing nicely with your approach and `org-clock-display` which seems to work fine with your approach. Maybe the small hickup with `org-columns` is acceptable. Go and post your answer. You also need to provide some means for editing the headings. Maybe, entering them (with mouse or keyboard) opens them. The overlays need to be updated if one leaves an edited heading. There are also problems with automagically updated items in the heading like todo-states.

Comment: Jagrg's solution works. To remove the overlays you can give them a property `(overlay-put overlay 'name "org-heading-upcased")` and remove them afterwards all at once with `(remove-overlays nil nil 'name "org-heading-upcased")`.
 
Imo it's probably better to just temporarily use another font for the headings (to see what this would do call it with `M-x set-face-font` and the select `org-level-1` and the new font. Too bad it doesn't seem possible to use all caps or small caps variants. You could use a font that is small caps only though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt with help from @Tobias and @Hubisan. You can toggle the overlay using the `toggle-headline-overlay` command. You can also edit the headline as usual. BTW this is a proof of concept. Expect some hiccups.

```el
(defvar headline-overlay-p nil)
(defvar headline-overlay-point nil)

(defun edit-headline ()
  (when (and (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
              headline-overlay-p)
    ;; First, upcase the last visited headline
    (when-let (point headline-overlay-point)
       (save-excursion
         (goto-char point)
         (when (save-excursion
                 (forward-line 0)
                 (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp))
          (let* ((beg (match-beginning 4))
                 (end (match-end 4))
                 (headline (match-string 4))
                 (ov (make-overlay beg end)))
            (overlay-put ov 'name 'upcased)
            (overlay-put ov 'display (upcase headline))))
        (setq headline-overlay-point nil)))
    ;; Then remove the overlay of the current headline
    (when (save-excursion
            (forward-line 0)
            (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp))
      (let ((beg (match-beginning 4))
            (end (match-end 4))
            (headline (match-string 4)))
        (if (and (overlays-at beg)
                 (eq (overlay-get (car (overlays-at beg)) 'name) 'upcased))
           (let ((ov (car (overlays-in beg end))))
             (when (eq (overlay-get ov 'name) 'upcased)
               (delete-overlay ov)
               (save-excursion
                 (goto-char beg)
                 (setq headline-overlay-point
                       (line-beginning-position))))))))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'edit-headline)

(defun toggle-headline-overlay ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (when (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp)
       (let ((beg (match-beginning 4))
             (end (match-end 4))
             (headline (match-string 4)))
         ;; Do we have an upcase overlay?
         (if (and (overlays-at beg)
                  (eq (overlay-get (car (overlays-at beg)) 'name) 'upcased))
             ;; If so delete the overlay
             (dolist (ov (overlays-in beg end))
               (when (eq (overlay-get ov 'name) 'upcased)
                 (delete-overlay ov)
                 (setq headline-overlay-p nil)))
           ;; Otherwise add the overlay
           (let ((ov (make-overlay beg end)))
             (overlay-put ov 'name 'upcased)
             (overlay-put ov 'display (upcase headline))
             (setq headline-overlay-p t))))))))
```